# Stop user from changing message when using ShareLinkTask in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, windows-phone

Ok so this is a pretty straightforward question however I cant find an answer simply using Google, does anyone know if I can grey out the message box when using ShareLinkTask to post a social update in Windows Phone so that the player can't fake a high score? Here's my current code:

```
ShareLinkTask shareLinkTask = new ShareLinkTask();

shareLinkTask.Title = "New Highscore in X";
shareLinkTask.LinkUri = new Uri("http://google.com", UriKind.Absolute);
shareLinkTask.Message = "Testing. Testing. 1, 2, 3...";

shareLinkTask.Show();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a no then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it using that feature. The aim of those *Task dialogs is to put the user in control so they have the ultimate say on what is posted and can cancel. If you want to post directly to Facebook without the user modifying the text you'll need to use the Facebook API directly and register your app and setup your own authentication specifically for your app...

Peter